# How to avoid populating previous field value when click add another in formset

Tags: python, django, inline-formset

I have used formset to add some contents to model. When i click edit, i can use add another or delete link to add or delete content. But when i click add another its populating with previous data. How to avoid that data?

[image: result which i'm getting]

I tried using initial but its shows error.

```
 ChoiceFormset1 = inlineformset_factory(
        Course,
        Materials_pdf,
        form=Materials_pdfForm,
        extra=0,
        intial =[{'chapter':'test'},{'pdf':'test'}, 
        {'course_type':'test'}]
        can_delete=True,
        fields=('chapter','pdf','course_type')
    )
```

what i wanted is new fields which is not populated with previous data, when i click add another. Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: whats previous data?

Comment: please check the image, last row is the one which created by clicking add another. So its populated with the data just above its row.